# Change password vs reset password

Tags: php, authentication, password-recovery

I have a page where a user can request a password reset link if they have forgotten the password to their account.  I also want to create a way for a user to change their password if they are already logged into their account.  Would it be better to create separate pages for each these different types of password resets or should I just change the form based on whether the user is logged in or not?  Does it really matter? Is there a general standard?

Comment: This topic is better suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I disagree as the intent of my question was not which is more user friendly, but what is more standard practice from a development stand point.  My intention is to stick with generally accepted programming standards and make things as secure as possible.  I can see why this question may be viewed as a ux question and I should have made the reasons for my question more apparent. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create separate pages.  Reset links(when users are not logged in) usually use a unique GET value.  When the user asks for a link to be sent to them, a value is inserted into the database.  When a person visits the reset page, the server will check the GET value entered into the URL.  If the GET value matches a unique value that is in the database, then the person is given the opportunity to put in a new password.  The unique values in databases are usually set to expire pretty quickly.  This prevents people from using brute force to reset someone else's password.

You don't want to mix the above with a simple password change that is initiated when a user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The password reset for a forgotten password process that you noted above is exactly how I am making that work.  I am glad that I am doing that correctly.  I am thinking that maybe I will just create a Update Account Info page where a user can change info including their password if needed.

Comment: Changing a password and resetting a password are two very different things.  Resetting a password can be done when the user is not logged in.  Changing a password only happens when the user is logged in AND knows their current password.